# Why tensor object attributes are removed by cloning?

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to clone a tensor in pytorch and would like to also clone the tensor attributes. Here is an example:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

a = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(1))
a.adapt = True                      # define tensor attribute

b = a.clone()                       # clone
```

In the example above, I would like `print(b.adapt)` to return `True`; however, I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "scratch.py", line 13, in <module>
>     print(b.adapt)
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'adapt'
> ```

I'm wondering why tensor object attributes are removed by cloning and how to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function [`torch.Tensor.clone`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.clone.html) performs a copy of the tensor's data, not a copy of the Python object. This is the reason why the adapt attribute of `a` is not available on `b`. Additionally, it will keep the same `grad_fn` on the newly created tensor:

Comment: Thanks. Is there an alternative to `.clone` to fix this? or the only way is to simply add `b.adapt = a.adapt`?

Comment: If you want to retain the graph on `b`, then using `clone` is the only way. Indeed, if you want to keep `adapt` on `b`, you will have to copy it yourself.